# Vuex getter doesn't recognize state change when add elements to an existing object.

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have an array called `tour_plan` in my state.

I have two actions in vuex actions.js

1. select_location
2. select_tour

In select_location I commit to mutation set_location like this

> commit("set_location",{day,location_id,location_name,location_payment})

then my mutation is

```
set_location(state, payload) {

        try {
            state.tour_plan.push(payload);
        } catch (error) {

        }

    },
```

What I did was just push the payload to the `tour_plan` array.

In my second action's mutation I don't push anything to the array. But I add new elements to the same array where I pushed already.

```
set_tour(state, payload) {
        try {

            state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_id = payload.tour;
            state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_payment = payload.tour_payment;
            state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_name = payload.tour_name;
            state.stage = 3;
        } catch (error) {

        }
    }
```

then I have a getter called cost

```
cost: (state) => {
        try {
            let arr = [];
            state.tour_plan.forEach(element => {

        console.log("THIS GETTER RUNS");

                if (element.location_name) {
                    let temp = {};
                    temp.day = element.day;
                    temp.item = 'Location fee';
                    temp.fee = element.location_payment
                    arr.push(temp);
                }
                if (element.tour_name) {

                    let temp = {};
                    temp.day = element.day;
                    temp.item = "Tour fee";
                    temp.fee = element.tour_payment;
                    arr.push(temp);
                }
            })
            return arr;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("ERR", error)
        }
    }
```

But the promblem here is this getter run at the first time when I push an object to the `tour_plan` array. But it won't run when I
change add elements to an already exsits object inside the array?

I have an array called `tour_plan` in my state.

I have two actions in vuex actions.js

1. select_location
2. select_tour

In select_location I commit to mutation set_location like this
commit("set_location",{day,location_id,location_name,location_payment})

then my mutation is

```
set_location(state, payload) {

        try {
            state.tour_plan.push(payload);
        } catch (error) {

        }

    },
```

What I did was just push the payload to the `tour_plan` array.

In my second action's mutation I don't push anything to the array. But I add new elements to the same array where I pushed already.

```
set_tour(state, payload) {
        try {

            state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_id = payload.tour;
            state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_payment = payload.tour_payment;
            state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_name = payload.tour_name;
            state.stage = 3;
        } catch (error) {

        }
    }
```

then I have a getter called cost

```
cost: (state) => {
        try {
            let arr = [];
            state.tour_plan.forEach(element => {

        console.log("THIS GETTER RUNS");

                if (element.location_name) {
                    let temp = {};
                    temp.day = element.day;
                    temp.item = 'Location fee';
                    temp.fee = element.location_payment
                    arr.push(temp);
                }
                if (element.tour_name) {

                    let temp = {};
                    temp.day = element.day;
                    temp.item = "Tour fee";
                    temp.fee = element.tour_payment;
                    arr.push(temp);
                }
            })
            return arr;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("ERR", error)
        }
    }
```

But the promblem here is this getter run at the first time when I push an object to the `tour_plan` array. But it won't run when I
change add elements to an already exsits object inside the array?

Comment: Did you check it in devtools ? Looks like page is loading before getting data from getters (means its getting old data from state) .

If this is the issue then you should use `routeBeforeEnter` and fetch required data here

Comment: Potentially a reactivity limitations issue. Check https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/ ,  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection and https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules and try to use `Vue.set(...)`

Comment: @TommyF I tried to use ```state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1] = { ...state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1],
                tour_id: payload.tour
            };```

Comment: But it also not trigger the getter

Comment: Maybe make an example highlighting the problem over at codesandbox.io, then it's much easier to help you.

Comment: @TommyF yes It was a reactivity limitation issue. =) and I update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the problem with the way I mutate.
This worked for me.

```
Vue.set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'tour_id', payload.tour)
Vue.set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'tour_payment', payload.tour_payment)
Vue.set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'tour_name', payload.tour_name)
```